# Is any valid address in Ethereum liable to receive payments?

Tags: accounts, addresses, eth-lightwallet

Suppose I have generated a valid ethereum address, there are a no of ways of doing so including using [Blockcypher's  Generate Address API](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/ethereum/#generate-address-endpoint), using [light-wallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet) etc. So I got a valid address, Now are these addresses published on blockchain? I mean any valid address is liable to receive payments ? Or anything else like private-public key pair or anything as such is needed (I am not good at this topic) ?

If nothing else is needed and we are ready to receive a payment as soon as a valid address is generated, I have another doubt (This part is probably specific to Light Wallet).
I was following [webawllet example of lightwallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet/blob/master/example/webwallet.html). It generates a new address by clicking the `show` button. So I get only a valid address as output (no private key,publick key, nothing else) and I have send some ethers to it. Will it receive the ethers? How can I claim these ethers ?

Answer (score 2):

1-the addresses are not published in the blockchain when created.

2-a valid address could be used to receive ethers

3-to control the funds belonging to an account you need to have the private key

4- read the webwallet [doc](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet) it is mentioned that :

> LightWallet is a HD wallet that **can store your private keys encrypted
>   in the browser** to allow you to run Ethereum dapps even if you're not
>   running a local Ethereum node. It uses BIP32 and BIP39 to generate an
>   HD tree of addresses from a randomly generated 12-word seed.

[and](https://github.com/ConsenSys/hooked-web3-provider)

> The Hooked Web3 Provider is a normal HTTP Web3 provider that allows
>   you to "hook in" **an external transaction signer** that can be used to
>   sign transactions for accounts not managed by the Ethereum client
>   (i.e., aren't managed by geth). An example transaction signer might be
>   an external program or device **that manages its own accounts and
>   private keys**. Together, the transaction signer and the web3 provider
>   will use the Ethereum client to place signed transactions on the
>   network.

without the private key wich was used to generate the address you could not get the ethers